# Get request with same tooken return results in Postman but unauthorized in C# code

Tags: python, c#, .net, rest, postman

I am posting a GET request to this URL with a bearer token:

http://api.viagogo.net/catalog/events?page_size=1000&sort=resource_version&min_resource_version=75939827358

It returns results in Postman as expected.

When i call the same api with same token in code (C#), i get unauthorized 401 response.

This is my code:

```
                var eventsUri = new Uri(eventsUrl);

                var httpClient = new HttpClient();
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "App Name");

                var eventResponseFromHttp = await httpClient.GetAsync(eventsUri);

                var responseContent = await eventResponseFromHttp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                var eventsFromHttps = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EventResponse>(responseContent);
```

But the weird thing is this:

If i call the same api without sort and min_resource_version query string parameters from code, it returns the results with 200:

http://api.viagogo.net/catalog/events?page_size=1000

I have no idea whats going on here. This is happening in a .Net Framework 4.7 application.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

UPDATE:

The same url with same token returns 200 and results using Python.

Comment: Can you paste some of your postman attempts? Some way to reproduce your stuff in order to try and help you more on this?

Comment: Reproducing will not be possible i think. I have a private token to access that endpoint which i cant post here

Comment: did you check the request structure and actual text format after sending it with postman and C#? Did you observe differences in `Authorization` header format?

Comment: How do we compare the 2?